# SQL how to eliminate or consolidate the result in less rows from multiple rows in my fact table

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, aggregate

How to eliminate or consolidate the result in less rows from multiple rows in the aggregation table?

Current situation is the first table#1 with 6 rows:

| cntrc_key | re_key | aup_key | insr_key | drvr_key | othr_key | lkp_key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 58046828 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 58046828 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 127270 | 0 |
| 58046828 | 0 | 45803863 | 0 | 0 | 127270 | 0 |
| 58046828 | 0 | 45803957 | 0 | 58245216 | 0 | 0 |
| 58046828 | 0 | 0 | 51021791 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 58046828 | 0 | 45803863 | 0 | 58245215 | 0 | 0 |

Expected is the next table#2 with 2 rows:

| cntrc_key | re_key | aup_key | insr_key | drvr_key | othr_key | lkp_key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 58046828 | 0 | 45803863 | 51021791 | 58245215 | 127270 | 0 |
| 58046828 | 0 | 45803957 | 51021791 | 58245216 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: You'll need to describe your specific rules about what consolidates, and what doesn't consolidate, and why.  For example, you've got a stray "insr_key" value (with all other values zero), and you've got a stray "othr_key" value (with all other values zero), and yet your 51021791 "insr_key" ends up against both of your rows, but your stray 127270 "othr_key" value doesn't end up against both rows.  What's the rule that dictates that?  (Plus what are any other rules that govern how the row consolidation should occur?)

Comment: I remember to have solved similar problem with MODEL clause, because it 's then easy to adapt the query to rules change and it scans the table only once, however as @Craig said: you should start by better explaining theses rules.

Answer (score 1):

You can use listagg to get all the rows per cntrc_key as **one row**.
Converting entire rows into a few rows will remove the meaning of data.

I tried the following.

```
select 
   cntrc_key
   ,LISTAGG(distinct re_key, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY re_key) as re_key
   ,LISTAGG(distinct AUP_KEY, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY AUP_KEY) as AUP_KEY
   ,LISTAGG(distinct INSR_KEY, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY INSR_KEY) as INSR_KEY
   ,LISTAGG(distinct DRVR_KEY, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY DRVR_KEY) as DRVR_KEY
   ,LISTAGG(distinct OTHR_KEY, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY OTHR_KEY) as OTHR_KEY
   ,LISTAGG(distinct LKP_KEY, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY LKP_KEY) as LKP_KEY
from table_name
group by cntrc_key;
```

| CNTRC_KEY | RE_KEY | AUP_KEY | INSR_KEY | DRVR_KEY | OTHR_KEY | LKP_KEY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 58046828 | 0 | 0,45803863,45803957 | 0,51021791 | 0,58245215,58245216 | 0,127270 | 0 |

Please let me know if this helps. Or let me know the rules on how you want your output to be.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option; see if it helps.

The first part (bunch of CTEs) is used to distinguish rows (`row_number` analytic function); `rn` is then used in "main" query for joins.

The final `where` clause eliminates all `null` values (`coalesce` function) and all `0` rows (`greatest` function).

```
SQL> with
  2  t_cnt as
  3    (select cntrc_key, row_number() over (order by null) rn from test),
  4  t_re as
  5    (select cntrc_key, re_key  , row_number() over (order by re_key)   rn from (select distinct cntrc_key, re_key   from test)),
  6  t_aup as
  7    (select cntrc_key, aup_key , row_number() over (order by aup_key)  rn from (select distinct cntrc_key, aup_key  from test)),
  8  t_insr as
  9    (select cntrc_key, insr_key, row_number() over (order by insr_key) rn from (select distinct cntrc_key, insr_key from test)),
 10  t_drvr as
 11    (select cntrc_key, drvr_key, row_number() over (order by drvr_key) rn from (select distinct cntrc_key, drvr_key from test)),
 12  t_othr as
 13    (select cntrc_key, othr_key, row_number() over (order by othr_key) rn from (select distinct cntrc_key, othr_key from test)),
 14  t_lkp as
 15    (select cntrc_key, lkp_key , row_number() over (order by lkp_key)  rn from (select distinct cntrc_key, lkp_key  from test)),
 16  --
 17  temp as
 18    (select distinct c.cntrc_key, nvl(re_key, 0)   re_key  , nvl(aup_key, 0)  aup_key,
 19                                  nvl(insr_key, 0) insr_key, nvl(drvr_key, 0) drvr_key,
 20                                  nvl(lkp_key, 0)  lkp_key
 21     from t_cnt c left join t_re   r on r.cntrc_key = c.cntrc_key and r.rn = c.rn
 22                  left join t_aup  a on a.cntrc_key = c.cntrc_key and a.rn = c.rn
 23                  left join t_insr i on i.cntrc_key = c.cntrc_key and i.rn = c.rn
 24                  left join t_drvr d on d.cntrc_key = c.cntrc_key and d.rn = c.rn
 25                  left join t_othr o on o.cntrc_key = c.cntrc_key and o.rn = c.rn
 26                  left join t_lkp  l on l.cntrc_key = c.cntrc_key and l.rn = c.rn
 27    )
 28  select cntrc_key, re_key, aup_key, insr_key, drvr_key, lkp_key
 29  from temp
 30  where coalesce(re_key, aup_key, insr_key, drvr_key, lkp_key) is not null
 31    and greatest(re_key, aup_key, insr_key, drvr_key, lkp_key) > 0;
```

Result:

```
 CNTRC_KEY     RE_KEY    AUP_KEY   INSR_KEY   DRVR_KEY    LKP_KEY
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
  58046828          0   45803957          0   58245216          0
  58046828          0   45803863   51021791   58245215          0

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

unpivot + pivot

```
with tt as
(
select distinct *
from t
unpivot (x for type in (cntrc_key,re_key,aup_key,insr_key,drvr_key,othr_key,lkp_key))
)
select *
from (select tt.*, row_number() over (partition by type order by x desc) rn from tt)
pivot (min(x) for type in ('CNTRC_KEY','RE_KEY','AUP_KEY','INSR_KEY','DRVR_KEY','OTHR_KEY','LKP_KEY'));

        RN 'CNTRC_KEY'   'RE_KEY'  'AUP_KEY' 'INSR_KEY' 'DRVR_KEY' 'OTHR_KEY'  'LKP_KEY'
---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1    58046828          0   45803957   51021791   58245216     127270          0
         2                          45803863          0   58245215          0           
         3                                 0                     0                      

3 rows selected.
```

... or just for fun

```
select cntrc_key,re_key,aup_key,insr_key,drvr_key,othr_key,lkp_key
from
(
select *
from t
model
unique single reference
dimension by 
(
dense_rank() over (order by cntrc_key desc) rn1,
dense_rank() over (order by re_key desc) rn2,
dense_rank() over (order by aup_key desc) rn3,
dense_rank() over (order by insr_key desc) rn4,
dense_rank() over (order by drvr_key desc) rn5,
dense_rank() over (order by othr_key desc) rn6,
dense_rank() over (order by lkp_key desc) rn7,
rownum rn
)
measures
(
cntrc_key,re_key,aup_key,insr_key,drvr_key,othr_key,lkp_key
)
rules
(
   cntrc_key[any,any,any,any,any,any,any,any] order by rn =
    nvl(min(cntrc_key)[cv(rn),any,any,any,any,any,any,any],0),
   re_key[any,any,any,any,any,any,any,any] order by rn = 
       nvl(min(re_key)[any,cv(rn),any,any,any,any,any,any],0),  
   aup_key[any,any,any,any,any,any,any,any] order by rn = 
      nvl(min(aup_key)[any,any,cv(rn),any,any,any,any,any],0),
   insr_key[any,any,any,any,any,any,any,any] order by rn = 
     nvl(min(insr_key)[any,any,any,cv(rn),any,any,any,any],0),
   drvr_key[any,any,any,any,any,any,any,any] order by rn = 
     nvl(min(drvr_key)[any,any,any,any,cv(rn),any,any,any],0),
   othr_key[any,any,any,any,any,any,any,any] order by rn = 
     nvl(min(othr_key)[any,any,any,any,any,cv(rn),any,any],0),
   lkp_key[any,any,any,any,any,any,any,any] order by rn =  
      nvl(min(lkp_key)[any,any,any,any,any,any,cv(rn),any],0)             
)
)
where (cntrc_key+re_key+aup_key+insr_key+drvr_key+othr_key+lkp_key) > 0
order by rn;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of the usage of MODEL clause for that kind of problem, however since you don't give any enough info about the rules you intent to apply, the result is not exactly what you show above, but at least it gives an idea:

```
WITH data(cntrc_key, re_key, aup_key, insr_key, drvr_key, othr_key, lkp_key) 
AS (
    SELECT  58046828, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  58046828, 0, 0, 0, 0, 127270, 0  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  58046828, 0, 45803863, 0, 0, 127270, 0 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  58046828, 0, 45803957, 0, 58245216, 0, 0  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  58046828, 0, 0, 51021791, 0, 0, 0  FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT  58046828, 0, 45803863, 0, 58245215, 0, 0 FROM DUAL -- UNION ALL
),
pdata AS (
    SELECT d.*
    FROM (
        SELECT rownum AS rn, d.* FROM DATA d
    ) d
)
SELECT DISTINCT cntrc_key, re_key, aup_key, insr_key,
drvr_key, othr_key, lkp_key FROM pdata 
MODEL
    PARTITION BY (cntrc_key)
    DIMENSION BY (rn)
    MEASURES(
        rn AS drn, 
            re_key, 0 AS next_re_key,
            aup_key, 0 AS next_aup_key, 
            insr_key, 0 AS next_insr_key, 
            drvr_key, 0 AS next_drvr_key,
            othr_key, 0 AS next_othr_key,
            lkp_key, 0 AS next_lkp_key
    )
    RULES 
    (
        next_re_key[ANY] = MIN(CASE WHEN re_key <> 0 THEN drn END)[rn >= cv(rn)],
        re_key[ANY] = CASE WHEN re_key[cv()] = 0 THEN NVL(re_key[cv()-1],re_key[cv()]) ELSE re_key[cv()] END,
        
        next_aup_key[ANY] = MIN(CASE WHEN aup_key <> 0 THEN drn END)[rn >= cv(rn)],
        aup_key[ANY] = CASE WHEN aup_key[cv()] = 0 THEN NVL(aup_key[cv()-1],aup_key[cv()]) ELSE aup_key[cv()] END,
        
        next_insr_key[ANY] = MIN(CASE WHEN insr_key <> 0 THEN drn END)[rn >= cv(rn)],
        insr_key[ANY] = CASE WHEN insr_key[cv()] = 0 THEN NVL(insr_key[cv()-1],insr_key[cv()]) ELSE insr_key[cv()] END,
        
        next_drvr_key[ANY] = MIN(CASE WHEN drvr_key <> 0 THEN drn END)[rn >= cv(rn)],
        drvr_key[ANY] = CASE WHEN drvr_key[cv()] = 0 THEN NVL(drvr_key[cv()-1],drvr_key[cv()]) ELSE drvr_key[cv()] END,
        
        next_othr_key[ANY] = MIN(CASE WHEN othr_key <> 0 THEN drn END)[rn >= cv(rn)],
        othr_key[ANY] = CASE WHEN othr_key[cv()] = 0 THEN NVL(othr_key[cv()-1],othr_key[cv()]) ELSE othr_key[cv()] END,
        
        next_lkp_key[ANY] = MIN(CASE WHEN lkp_key <> 0 THEN drn END)[rn >= cv(rn)],
        lkp_key[ANY] = CASE WHEN lkp_key[cv()] = 0 THEN NVL(lkp_key[cv()-1],lkp_key[cv()]) ELSE lkp_key[cv()] END,
        
        
        re_key[ANY] = NVL(re_key[next_re_key[cv()]],NVL(re_key[cv()-1],0)),
        aup_key[ANY] = NVL(aup_key[next_aup_key[cv()]],NVL(aup_key[cv()-1],0)),
        insr_key[ANY] = NVL(insr_key[next_insr_key[cv()]],NVL(insr_key[cv()-1],0)),
        drvr_key[ANY] = NVL(drvr_key[next_drvr_key[cv()]],NVL(drvr_key[cv()-1],0)),
        othr_key[ANY] = NVL(othr_key[next_othr_key[cv()]],NVL(othr_key[cv()-1],0)),
        lkp_key[ANY] = NVL(lkp_key[next_lkp_key[cv()]],NVL(lkp_key[cv()-1],0))

    )
;


CNTRC_KEY|RE_KEY|AUP_KEY |INSR_KEY|DRVR_KEY|OTHR_KEY|LKP_KEY|
---------+------+--------+--------+--------+--------+-------+
 58046828|     0|45803863|51021791|58245216|  127270|      0|
 58046828|     0|45803957|51021791|58245216|  127270|      0|
 58046828|     0|45803863|51021791|58245215|  127270|      0|
```